# SSH access a remote server through 2 other servers

Tags: linux, ssh, web-server, remote-access, ssh-tunnel

I would like to keep checking a log file(named myapp.log) located on a remote web server & keep the up-to-date content of this file showing to me (by using the linux command `tail -f myapp.log`). The name of the remote web server is **service**

This remote web server can only be accessed through other 2 remote servers (named **Alpha** & **Beta**). So, I have to establish several SSH connections in order to access the remote **service** server. like below:

**Step 1,** SSH to **Alpha** server:

`ssh myname@alpha.server.org` (password is required)

(Now, I'm on **Alpha** server)

**Step 2,** SSH to **Beta** server through **Alpha**:

`ssh beta.server.org` (password is required)

(Now, I am on **Beta**)

**Step 3,** SSH to **service** server through **Beta**:

`sudo ssh service` (password is required)

(Now, I am on **Service** server)

**Step 4,** open my server log file:

```
tail -f myapp.log
```

Every time, I have to execute the above commands on terminal in order to access **myapp.log** file. The most boring part is the connection only keep alive for 20min, then I have to run those commands again to access the **myapp.log** file.

Is there a way that I could keep the connections alive all the time, that I can see the **myapp.log** content all the time without making those SSH connections every 20min ?

I need this for both Mac machine & Windows 7 machine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you knew why the server drops your connection..

On Mac OSX, you can set the timeout for Terminal.app in `/.ssh/config` put:

> ServerAliveInterval 300
>   ServerAliveCountMax 3

In windows I assume you're using putty, under the `Connection` option, set the
 `Seconds between keepalives` to a non 0 number.

The Mac option is for your user's personal connections, if you want to change the behavior for any user, set it in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`